# How to move a div area to a particular id on a click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 10 x 10 board and a button (in the demo given below I've minimized that to 3 x 3 ). When users click on the button the system generates a random number 1 to 9.

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",function(){

var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
num = num % 9;/*generate a random no between 0 to 8*/
num = num + 1;/*generate a random no between 1 to 9*/
  alert(num);/* check the no*/
  if(num === "1"){
    /*i need to move the red circle to box no 1*/
    }else if(num === "2"){
      /*i need to move the red circle to box no 2*/
      }
  /*and so on upto 9*/
  });
```

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;height:100%;
  }

#board{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  
  }
#one,#two,#three{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
  }
.flag-point{
  width:100px;
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  }
#a8,#a2,#a4,#a6 {
  background-color:green;
  }

#crcl{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:red;
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-radius:50%;
  }
```

```html
<div id="crcl"> </div> <button id="btn">move circle</button>

<div id="board">
  <div id="one">
    <div id="a9" class="flag-point">9</div>
    <div id="a8" class="flag-point">8</div>
    <div id="a7" class="flag-point">7</div>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <div id="a6" class="flag-point">6</div>
    <div id="a5" class="flag-point">5</div>
    <div id="a4" class="flag-point">4</div>
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <div id="a3" class="flag-point">3</div>
    <div id="a2" class="flag-point">2</div>
    <div id="a1" class="flag-point">1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here each box has an id from a1 to a9. When users press the button each time I need to move the red circular div according to this random number to the corresponding box (ie, if you get a number 3 the red circle needs to move to box3(#a3)). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/getElementById) and [HTMLNode#appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

That way you move the circle to be a child of the certain divs.

When you do appendChild on an existing node, it will be detached from wherever it is right now, and moved to the new parent.

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",function(){

var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
num = num % 9;/*generate a random no between 0 to 8*/
num = num + 1;/*generate a random no between 1 to 9*/
  alert(num);/* check the no*/
  var parent = document.getElementById('a'+num);
  var circle = document.getElementById('crcl');
  parent.appendChild(circle);
  /*and so on upto 9*/
  });
```

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;height:100%;
  }

#board{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  
  }
#one,#two,#three{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
  }
.flag-point{
  width:100px;
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  }
#a8,#a2,#a4,#a6 {
  background-color:green;
  }

#crcl{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:red;
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-radius:50%;
  }
```

```html
<div id="crcl"> </div> <button id="btn">move circle</button>

<div id="board">
  <div id="one">
    <div id="a9" class="flag-point">9</div>
    <div id="a8" class="flag-point">8</div>
    <div id="a7" class="flag-point">7</div>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <div id="a6" class="flag-point">6</div>
    <div id="a5" class="flag-point">5</div>
    <div id="a4" class="flag-point">4</div>
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <div id="a3" class="flag-point">3</div>
    <div id="a2" class="flag-point">2</div>
    <div id="a1" class="flag-point">1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tnx...great  idea..!!

Comment: Well, there's a lot to learn for you then :-) I congratulate you on doing it the javascript way and not grasping to jQuery like most people do :-) Use the MDN docs I linked to, they do a terrific job at explaining the core methods.

Answer (score 1):

you could append the ball to the correct div, not sure if its the best idea, but it does move the ball in there

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",function(){

var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
num = num % 9;/*generate a random no between 0 to 8*/
num = num + 1;/*generate a random no between 1 to 9*/
    moveBall(num);
});

function moveBall(num) {
  var ball = document.getElementById('crcl');
  var square = document.getElementById('a' + num);
  square.appendChild(ball);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Added a little more css to auto center the circle inside the square.

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  num = num % 9; /*generate a random no between 0 to 8*/
  num = num + 1; /*generate a random no between 1 to 9*/
  var currentSquare = document.getElementById("a"+num);
  var circle = document.getElementById("crcl");
  circle.style.display = "block";
  currentSquare.appendChild(circle);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#board {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
#one,
#two,
#three {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
.flag-point {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#a8,
#a2,
#a4,
#a6 {
  background-color: green;
}
#crcl {
  display: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="crcl"></div>
<button id="btn">move circle</button>
<div id="board">
  <div id="one">
    <div id="a9" class="flag-point">9</div>
    <div id="a8" class="flag-point">8</div>
    <div id="a7" class="flag-point">7</div>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <div id="a6" class="flag-point">6</div>
    <div id="a5" class="flag-point">5</div>
    <div id="a4" class="flag-point">4</div>
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <div id="a3" class="flag-point">3</div>
    <div id="a2" class="flag-point">2</div>
    <div id="a1" class="flag-point">1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tnx...this will help me little more

Answer (score 1):

You can use it with jquery  like that  :

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",function(){

var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
num = num % 9;/*generate a random no between 0 to 8*/
num = num + 1;/*generate a random no between 1 to 9*/
  alert(num);/* check the no*/
  var parent = $("#a"+num);
  var circle = $("#crcl");
  parent.append(circle);
  /*and so on upto 9*/
  });
```

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;height:100%;
  }

#board{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  
  }
#one,#two,#three{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
  }
.flag-point{
  width:100px;
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  }
#a8,#a2,#a4,#a6 {
  background-color:green;
  }

#crcl{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:red;
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-radius:50%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="crcl"> </div> <button id="btn">move circle</button>

<div id="board">
  <div id="one">
    <div id="a9" class="flag-point">9</div>
    <div id="a8" class="flag-point">8</div>
    <div id="a7" class="flag-point">7</div>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <div id="a6" class="flag-point">6</div>
    <div id="a5" class="flag-point">5</div>
    <div id="a4" class="flag-point">4</div>
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <div id="a3" class="flag-point">3</div>
    <div id="a2" class="flag-point">2</div>
    <div id="a1" class="flag-point">1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this :

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",function(){

  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  num = num % 9;/*generate a random no between 0 to 8*/
  num = num + 1;/*generate a random no between 1 to 9*/

  var target = document.querySelector('#a'+num);
  var circle = document.querySelector('#crcl');
  circle.remove();
  target.append(circle);
  });
```

Here's the demo : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PbOaKb